# Why doesn't Neo4j show any system information (:sysinfo) in the browser?

Tags: neo4j

I recently upgraded to Neo4j 4.0.6. (Community Edition)

After upgrading my "old" Neo4j database the browser :sysinfo command (Chrome and Safari) doesn't show any information. It just displays the empty tables for Store Size, id Allocation etc.

All the tables and labels are shown as in Neo4j 3.x but no values are prompted. It doesn't matter if I change the "Use Database" settings (switch to system and back) or if stop and restart the server. No entries for :sysinfo show up.

Any idea how to reactivate the DB :sysinfo in the browser interface again is greatly appreciated.

Krid

Answer (score 0):

I tend to think its an issue with recent versions.
It caused me to believe a multi upgrade store was incorrect.

So I went the long 'dump to cypher and reimport' route.

After node import, sysinfo was working (4.1 CE)
This behaviour appeared when I added relations
CALL db.schema.visualization() is broken too (no graph tab)

What a time loss, I tell you.
Wont count the days

Somewhere I read to reset the indexes, be sure btree was used.
No, it didnt work.

your next move is to file an issue

It seems ppl also have this issue since 3.5 w/ clusters
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues?q=is%3Aissue+sysinfo